# timed display of div

Tags: jquery, css, html, redefine

all i need is some client side code jQuery or JS that will alter the divs style after **X seconds**

like  `visibility : hidden;` OR  `max-height : 50px;`

or switch the class \ id of the DIV **(** *preferred* **)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // Change the style here... If using jQuery, it turns
  $('#my_divs').css({'visibility':'hidden', 'max-height':'50px'})
  // or
  $('#my_divs').addClass('my-custom-class');
}, x_seconds);
```

Comment: Don't need the quotes around property names.

Comment: You do if it contains special characters, like 'max-height'. Dunno, I tend to put them when referring to css attributes, but it's just a personal preference.

Comment: @gradbot: No, you don't in that case. Property names are only treated as strings, they're never evaluated as variables.

Answer (score 4):

Plain JavaScript solution:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('your_div_id').className = 'new_class_name';
}, X * 1000); // X = number of seconds
```

Comment: this will also remove other classes, you should append the `className`

Comment: True but I wasn't sure what the OP wanted, he just said "switch the class".

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout('changeStyle()', 1000); //milliseconds
});

function changeStyle() {
    //do something useful
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout(changeStyle, 1000)` instead.

Comment: will rest of the page be interactive for the timeout period or not.. and please tell how to specify the CSSs

Comment: Yes, the page will still be interactive

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method that I use on a current production website.

```
$("#divStampWrapper").delay(1500).fadeIn("fast").delay(2500).animate({ top: -250 }, 2500).delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
```

Explanation:
Basically it grabs the div which holds an image, waits 1.5 seconds and then starts fading it in to view.  Once the fade in effect is finished, it waits another 2.5 seconds and starts moving it upward to the new top position.  It then waits another 2.5 seconds and starts a fade out.
I know it's a bit more than you asked for, but it's a good example of what can be done with the timer.

Answer (score 0):

IF u wanna show time after some sec again and again 
then use

```
setIntervel('changeStyle()',1000);
```

and u just wanna use time just once then use

```
setTimeout('changeStyle()',1000);
function changeStyle() {
 // code to display time
}
```